# Codeigniter multi app same controller/view

Tags: php, codeigniter, share

simple question:

It's possible to create a multi codeigniter app that share the same controller/model/view but use different config.php and database.php file ?

I want to install my app in different folder but use only one folder with the controller/model/view. With this way if I want to change a controller file (for example) I do it only once and not on every single application.

Thanks for help!

Comment: if you only need different config files - you can use different environments... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html

Answer (score 1):

The config.php and database.php are normal PHP file, so you can put any code inside!

One approach would be to identify the site on which you are in your `index.php` file, and define a global constant that could be used throughout the site.

For instance:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME' === 'my-domain-1') define('DOMAIN', 'domain-1');
elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME' === 'my-domain-2') define('DOMAIN', 'domain-2');
else die("Unknown domain");
```

Then, in your `config.php`, you could do, for each configuration option you want to change according to the site:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = (DOMAIN === 'domain-1') ? 'a-strong-encryption-key-1' : 
                            (DOMAIN === 'domain-2') ? 'a-strong-encryption-key-2' : 
                            '??';
```

And for the `database.php`:

```
$active_group = (DOMAIN === 'domain-1') ? 'db-domain-1' : 
                (DOMAIN === 'domain-2') ? 'db-domain-2' : 
                '??';

$db['db-domain-1'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'domain-1-db-host',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'domain-1-db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['db-domain-2'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'domain-2-db-host',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'domain-2-db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

This is actually what I use for my dev and prod server (using the `ENVIRONMENT` constant).